# When does loading the image happen, with respect to parsing HTML, loading and parsing CSS, and loading and executing JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

From https://blog.logrocket.com/how-browser-rendering-works-behind-the-scenes-6782b0e8fb10, I learned that

- parsing HTML (which I think is the same as creating DOM out of HTML) occurs asynchronously with downloading and parsing CSS style sheets
- parsing HTML (which I think is the same as creating DOM out of HTML) halts and waits for downloading and executing JS scripts, by default
- executing JS scripts which access CSS style sheets halts and  waits for  downloading and parsing the CSS style sheets.

When embedding some resources in HTML, for example,

```
<img src="/url/to/image.png" alt="Image" width="200" height="67"/>
```

when does loading the image happen, with respect to parsing HTML documents, loading and parsing CSS style sheets, and loading and executing JS scripts?

Comment: my understanding is that the HTTP request to download the image is launched as soon as the img tag is added to the DOM (so effectively as soon as that element is encountered in the HTML by the browser).

Comment: without halting  the parsing of the remaining part of the HTML document into DOM?

Comment: as far as I know it doesn't halt it, but you could probably set up an experiement to be certain (just try and download a very large image, you can soon see if it stops everything else from rendering)

Comment: Some ideas here (2017-09): https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/how-to-optimize-image-loading-on-your-website-855020fb41ae

Comment: And https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/.